# Best API design for related videos feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, rest

I have to design a RESTful API for getting videos related to another. The user can filter the list using certain attributes such as date, video type s.o. The value of the attribute may be absent, in which case all the values for the given attribute of the video to which we are finding related content are considered.

I am using Ruby on Rails.

Alternatives are:

```
 1. video/ID/related/ATTRIBUTE?query="value of ATTRIBUTE"
 2. video/ID/related?attribute="value of ATTRIBUTE"
 3. video/ID/related/ATTRIBUTE/VALUE_OF_ATTRIBUTE
```

I have to mention that, as I said before, the value may be absent, there is only one ATTRIBUTE based on which the filtering occurs, the value is singular, selected from a fixed list.

Comment: I'd vote for 2) so you can evolve your rules easily

Answer (score 1):

**First Step: Get ALL Related Videos**

In the first step you `GET` *all* videos related to a given video. If this video is at

```
GET /video/{id}
```

then the related videos can be at

```
GET /video/{id}/related
```

This would return the *full* list of *all* related videos.

**Second Step: Filter the List**

If you want to *filter* this list, use query parameters as in your second alternative.

```
GET /video/{id}/related?some_attribute=foo&some_other_attribute=bar
```

**Reason Against 1. and 3.**

Your alternatives 1. and 3. introduce a new sub-resource `ATTRIBUTE` of the list of the related videos. This sub-resource does not correspond to anything in the list of related videos.

**Solution**

Use the second alternative.

Comment: The problem is that I always filter by one attribute, nothing more, and this attribute may not have a value, in such case I would end up using the params like this:
GET /video/{id}/related?some_attribute=""

Comment: @RaduStoenescu That's not a problem. Empty query parameters are OK.

Comment: That's true, but I still have to document the mutual exclusivity of the attributes and check for proper usage. In case one or 3 this is taken care by the routing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the mutual exclusivity of the attributes'?

Comment: There can only be one filter. e.g: there won't be another `some_other_attribute`